# How to verify a service is listening on both ipv4 and ipv6?

Tags: linux, networking, openssl, ssl, https

I want to check whether https service is listening on both IPv6 and IPv4.

And also when I am accessing url via browser, I want to know request is served by IPv4 or IPv6.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `netstat`:

```
# netstat -tlnp | grep httpd
# netstat -tlnp | grep apache
# netstat -tlnp | grep nginx
# netstat -tlnp | grep ...
```

Then check that you get a line for each IP protocol version (tcp and tcp6).

```
#!/bin/bash

ns=$(netstat -tlnp | grep httpd)

if grep 'tcp ' <<< "$ns" >/dev/null; then
    echo "httpd has a listening IPv4 socket."
fi

if grep 'tcp6 ' <<< "$ns" >/dev/null; then
    echo "httpd has a listening IPv6 socket."
fi
```

Note that you'll need root privileges with `netstat` if you want to see processes which belong to root (such as the Apache master process). If you want to use `netstat` as a standard user, remove the `-p` option and `grep` by IP and port instead. For instance:

```
$ netstat -tln | grep '0.0.0.0:80'
$ netstat -tln | grep '127.0.0.1:80'
$ netstat -tln | grep '::1:80'
```

Note that in this case, you don't need to `grep` again on `tcp` or `tcp6`, since the IP you're `grep`-ing already provides the information you are looking for. Whether you should look for 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 depends on your web server configuration.

Comment: I only get below line:                                                                                  tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN      13734/httpd

Comment: not always, I only have tcp6 for apache, yet I connect to my site using ipv4.

Comment: @Archemar You are probably using IPv6 transport over IPv4, a compatibility workaround put in place for the IPv4 > IPv6 transition phase. Also note that [Apache supports IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488299/dont-see-apache-running-in-netstat/490185#490185). (Gaurav KS: I edited my answer)

Answer (score 4):

`lsof` is also useful.

You can see all listening addresses and established connections of `nginx` using IPv4 and IPv6 respectively as follows (run as root):

```
lsof -c nginx -a -i4
lsof -c nginx -a -i6
```

Show all connections of Google Chrome on the client host, both v4 and v6:

```
lsof -c chrome -a -i
```

Comment: I am a root user. and i cant see tcp6 in netstat output.

Comment: Then you can conclude that your servers are listening only on IPv4 address.